# Need WebMethod to Return Entire Query Contents, Not First Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asmx, webmethod

I have a web method that works, but the raw DB query I'm feeding into it returns a list of items, whereas the web method only returns the first item.  I need it to return the entire list rather than just the first item.  How do I do that?

```
[WebMethod]
        public DTO_getList getList(int partID, int offset, int next)
        {
            DTO_getList user = new DTO_getList();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            try
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                string sqlQuery = "LENGTHY QUERY THAT RETURNS A LIST OF STUFF";

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                //  Add the parameters to be passed into the DB
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partID", partID);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offset", offset);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", next);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    //  Grab the records
            user.date = myReader["Date"].ToString();
            //MORE STUFF BEING RETURNED

                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                //user.valid = false;

                return user;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
                return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are updating the same User instance with all the rows returned by your query and return that instance.

Instead, create a List of Users (System.Collections.Generic.List) and for each row add a new Uer instance:

```
myUsersList = new List<User>();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    myUsersList.Add(new User()
    {
        data = myReader["Date"].ToString(),
        ........
    }
}

return myUsersList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

create class "User"

and using this code

```
[WebMethod]
public List<User>  getList(int partID, int offset, int next)
    {

        List<User> userList = new List<User>();


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            string sqlQuery = "LENGTHY QUERY THAT RETURNS A LIST OF STUFF";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
            //  Add the parameters to be passed into the DB
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partID", partID);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offset", offset);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", next);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            User us = new User();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                //  Grab the records
                us.Date = myReader["Date"].ToString();
                //MORE STUFF BEING RETURNED
                userList.Add(us);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            //user.valid = false;

            return userList;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return userList;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't return the list (although the code didn't break.)  It returns "<ArrayOfUser/>"

Answer (score 0):

Use DTO_getList as a list in your return statement:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public List<DTO_getList> getList(int partID, int offset, int next)
    {
        List<DTO_getList> list = new List<DTO_getList>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            string sqlQuery = "LENGTHY QUERY THAT RETURNS A LIST OF STUFF";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
            //  Add the parameters to be passed into the DB
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partID", partID);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offset", offset);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", next);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                 DTO_getList user = new DTO_getList();
                //  Grab the records
                user.date = myReader["Date"].ToString();
                //MORE STUFF BEING RETURNED
                list.Add(user);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            //user.valid = false;
            return list;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

            return list;
       }
    }
```

Other option: Use DTO_getList as an array in your return statement:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public DTO_getList[] getList(int partID, int offset, int next)
    {
       List<DTO_getList> list = new List<DTO_getList>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
          //Same repetitive code here
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            //user.valid = false;
            return list.ToArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

            return list.ToArray();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Huh.  It, too, simply returns "<ArrayOfSTO_getList/>"